# does ZFS/BTRFS RAID knows that only data needs to be synced?

Tags: linux, raid, btrfs, zfs

AFAIK plain MD software ex.: RAID1 doesn't know that it should only sync real data from one disk to another, so it syncs all the blocks unneededly, even if there is no real data on the given block. Wasting disk performance, disk lifetime, CPU and risking disk failure for the too long RAID rebuilds.

**The Question:** since ZFS/BTRFS is a filesystem itself, if I would use RAID1 withing them (since they know RAID although they are filesystems) does it know that it should only sync the real DATA and not blindly all the blocks?

Answer (score 1):

If you talk about replacement of failed disk:
ZFS (at least on Solaris) keep hashes of blocks so it know which one is out of sync and need to be synchronised.

But if we talk about ordinary write operation hardware RAID controller, `md`, `LVM` know which block on which disk was stored and do the write operation on other.